# AbanteCart language definition API updateDescriptions vs replaceDescriptions

Tags: e-commerce

I am working on extension for new AbanteCart version 1.1.3

New API for language there are updateDescriptions and replaceDescriptions

I see this code 

`$this->language->replaceDescriptions('banner_descriptions',                                        array('banner_id' => (int)$banner_id),
                       array($language_id => $update) );`

I am not clear what is the difference and when to use update vs replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replaceDescriptions method checks is language description for chosen language is already exists in database. 
updateDescriptions method just makes update. When you use it be sure that language description exists.